# Signing assembly with assemblies inside

Tags: c#, merge, .net-assembly, assembly-signing

I have an assembly which contains assemblies (made with ILMerge). I wanted to sign this assembly with AL.exe but it turned up that AL.exe cannot sign assemblies which contains assemblies. How can I sign assembly which contains assemblies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ILMergeSigned.aspx) it is.

> Under the default settings, the merged assembly is not signed. This can be a problem if the software that uses it requires an assembly with a strong name. Luckily, ILMerge includes an option that permits the merged assembly to be signed using a key file, which will usually have an extension of SNK. Key files can be generated by Visual Studio or the strong name tool (sn.exe) that ships with the .NET Framework.
> To merge assemblies and sign the result, you should use the /keyfile switch. The switch is followed by a colon (:) and the name of the key file.

Example:

```
ilmerge /out:Merged.dll /keyfile:key.snk Primary.dll Secondary.dll
```